# Performing searches in Jira

Tags: search, jira

I am not even sure this question belongs here, first question I post, so be gentle :)

I am looking into integrating Jira with our application, and we would like to provide the users with a web link in our app which upon the user clicking will open a new page with all the tickets open for a given user.

We are looking into doing this by jira query language, and passing the query as a parameter in the URL, the issue is that the query we need to perform must be: search all tickets containing in their body this user id. And I am not sure what would be the correct sintax for that..

Can any of you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Define a suitable query and run it, then look for the icon that shares the filter. The URL format is pretty simple and can be modified to pass in whatever parameters you need dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can pass arbitrary JQL in a JIRA URL, but you could do what you want by setting up a filter for all open issues for current user, saving it and sharing it with all users who you want to be able to access it via the URL.  See [the JIRA docs](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=267257855) for details.

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy enough - please navigate to your profile page in JIRA (user menu in the top right corner, first link), on the main profile page you'll find a *Filters* popup menu on the right, which features a couple of predefined queries to get you started, e.g.:

- *Assigned & Open*, which yields the JQL query
  [`resolution = Unresolved AND assignee = currentUser()`](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20assignee%20=%20currentUser%28%29)
- *Assigned & In Progress*, which yields the JQL query
  [`status = "3" AND assignee = currentUser()`](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=status%20=%20%223%22%20AND%20assignee%20=%20currentUser%28%29)

All this is URL driven, i.e. the query is defined as a respective URL and navigated to accordingly, as demonstrated with the linked example queries above (these are targeting the official [JIRA project](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA)).

You can easily refine these queries to your liking in turn and use the resulting URL from your app.

Good luck!